# How to install Phonegap Latest Plugin for Aptana 3.4?

Tags: cordova, aptana

I have Latest phonegap-2.9.1 zip file downloaded from the official website of phonegap. But I don't know how to install it and what I have downloaded. I'm using Aptana 3.4 and want to develop Android Application by using it. If this is possible to install it OFFLINE? if yes, then HOW?